# How can I get SQL that not out of date?

Tags: sql, validation, date

I have got a premium table like this:

```
id | user_id | start_date          | websize
 1 | 1       | 2012-08-05 10:10:10 | 1024
```

The premium accounts are for one year. I would like to get all rows where `start_date and + 1 year is not > date('Y-m-d')`...

Sorry for poor english..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get all the rows with a `start_date` that aren't more than a year old:

Using MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM premiumTable
WHERE start_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Using MSSQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM premiumTable
WHERE start_date > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: $99 on MySQL, owing to the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss` (and the PHP `date()` call)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Most likely. Just wanted to cover my butt.

Comment: Thank you. YOu understand correctly, I just could'not translate.. :-)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Would you rather bet $99 or 100k rep? :)